# Relative layout not putting button in place

Tags: android, button, screen, android-relativelayout

im using this code;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and for some reason this is not working in the emulator with 540x960.  The button appear in the middle of the emulator.

In my droid2 it works correctly.

[image]

the left picture show how it works in my droid 2 cellphone, and right side show how is working in the HTC sensationXe emulator

Comment: What OS version is the emulator? Also maybe you should anchor the TextView to something.

Comment: i already update my question and i upload some pictures so u can see the problem

Answer (score 1):

I Already found the answer of the problem. i was compiling my app as anddroid 1.5, now i added this to the manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
     android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

and i compile to android 1.6

now the is in the place it has to be

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an anchor point to your TextView.. try to align the text view in the left of the button or in its right side and the problem should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Orientation attribute does not work for Relative Layouts. Try following

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@id/helloid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: this doesnt work,i already upload some picture about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your XML by this and it will work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```